# Update Progress bar from Class' BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#

I am trying to update progress bar from the class that does the copying

In the my copy class I have

```
public event EventHandler Copy_OnProgressChange;

private void CopyWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler handler = Copy_OnProgressChange;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
        }
```

And in the main class

```
CopyList[i].Copy_OnProgressChange += CopyProgressMessage;

    void CopyProgressMessage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //update progressBar with percentage
    }
```

As you can see I can not pass percentage from ProgressChangedEventArgs to eventhandler. Is there an easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change your event to be `EventHandler<ProgressChangedEventArgs>`, so that it will pass the derived type with the progress property.

Comment: It did take me a while to understand how this work, but it does work. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like your event handler isn't structured correctly... It requires the second argument to be: `ProgressChangedEventArgs` instead of EventArgs...

`ProgressChangedEventArgs` has a property named: `ProgressPercentage`.